# UITableView iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am having a table view with 5 sections each section contains a only 1 row each row displays a customized cell.  Everything is working properly but section zero is repeating at section four I am not able to trace this. This is my code.

```
-(void) setUpActivityView {
    [self createViews];
}


#pragma  mark Table View methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 5;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.section == 0) { 
        return 167;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        return 200;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 2) {
        return 115;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 3) {
        return 90;
    }
    else {
        return 155;
    }

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"customCellIdentifier";

    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        _notificationCell = (NotificationsCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (_notificationCell == nil) {
            _notificationCell = [[[NotificationsCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        }

        _notificationCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        return _notificationCell;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0) {
         _topMatchCell = (TopMatchCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (_topMatchCell == nil) {
            _topMatchCell = [[[TopMatchCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];   
        }

        _topMatchCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        return _topMatchCell;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        _recentlyViewedCell = (RecentlyViewedHomesCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (_recentlyViewedCell == nil) {
            _recentlyViewedCell = [[[RecentlyViewedHomesCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

        _recentlyViewedCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        return _recentlyViewedCell;
    } else if (indexPath.section == 3 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        _feedbackCell = (FeedbackCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (_feedbackCell == nil) {
            _feedbackCell = [[[FeedbackCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

        _feedbackCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        return _feedbackCell;
    }
    else {
        _activityTimeLineCell = (ActivityTimeLineCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (_activityTimeLineCell == nil) {
            _activityTimeLineCell = [[[ActivityTimeLineCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

        _activityTimeLineCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        return _activityTimeLineCell;
   }
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}


- (void)initializeSubViews {
    _mainTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 412) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
}


- (void)configureLayoutOfSubViews {
    self._mainTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Home_Setup1-bg.png"]];
//    UIColor *lSeperatorColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"line_bg.png"]];
//    [self._mainTableView setSeparatorColor:lSeperatorColor];
}


- (void)setStylesForSubViews {
    _mainTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    _mainTableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    _mainTableView.scrollsToTop = NO;
}

- (void)setStateForSubViews {

}

- (void)registerTargets {
    _mainTableView.delegate = self;
    _mainTableView.dataSource = self;
}

-(void)addToParentsView {
     [self addSubview:_mainTableView];
}

-(void) createViews {
    [self initializeSubViews];
    [self configureLayoutOfSubViews];
    [self setStylesForSubViews];
    [self setStateForSubViews];
    [self registerTargets];
    [self addToParentsView];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use different cell identifiers for different cells. As new cells scroll into your view, old cells that scrolled out of your view will be reused based on the identifier you provide on dequeueing.

Let me guess, on load your fifth cell is not within your view?

Comment: yes my fifth cell is out of view,  i will check by having different cell identifier.